# How to set system path(`$PATH`) to default value permanently?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

i accidentally change my path to this

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/josh/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

how can i change that $PATH into this permanently?
like this

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

i tried every solution but when i close the terminal and open it again, the path still not change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the first place ([See also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))? Seems you want to get rid of `snap`, but there are better ways than changing PATH.

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` is a colon-sepatated list of directories that your shell searches, looking for commands to execute.

Set your `PATH` in your `~/.bashrc` by adding the following line to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

After you save the changes to the file, run the following command in each open shell to apply the changes or simply log out and log back in:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: i'm new to linux os, so it's still very confusing to use terminal. where can i find the ~/.bashrc file?